# Python: How can I return the same array, where the ith element is removed in each row?

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have a list of lists:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5], [11,22,33,44,55], [111,222,333,444,555]]
```

How can I simply return the same list, where the ith element of each row is removed, given any i?
For example if i = 2, we get:
    `[[1,2,4,5], [11,22,44,55], [111,222,444,555]]`.

I tried:
slicing, but got into trouble with things like `list[0:i]` which fails when i = 0.
Getting index values using `my_list.index(i)`, but this fails since the function wants to match strings.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You can `del` ith item.

```
i = 2
for x in my_list:
    del x[i]

...
return my_list # Same list reference
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 4, 5], [11, 22, 44, 55], [111, 222, 444, 555]]
```

Comment: Isn't using `del` causing one hellofa "side-effect" on the original list?

Comment: Yes, it is. If you need to remove an element **in-place**, you will always need that side effect. If you are referring to my comment below the other answer, I *meant **list comprehension** is not advised if it introduces side-effects in the original list. What is we are use that list again elsewhere?*. :)

Comment: Without asking a new question, what if I want to use the list again later?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, you don't need to modify the original list and you are fine with the original list's *copy* where i-th element of every inner list was popped. List comprehensions and slices come to the rescue!

```
def pop_ith(lst, i):
    return [x[0:i] + x[i+1:] for x in lst]

>>> a = [[1,2,3,4,5], [11,22,33,44,55], [111,222,333,444,555]] 
>>> pop_ith(a,1)
[[1, 3, 4, 5], [11, 33, 44, 55], [111, 333, 444, 555]]
>>> pop_ith(a,0)
[[2, 3, 4, 5], [22, 33, 44, 55], [222, 333, 444, 555]]
>>> pop_ith(a,4)
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [11, 22, 33, 44], [111, 222, 333, 444]]
>>> pop_ith(a,6)
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [11, 22, 33, 44, 55], [111, 222, 333, 444, 555]]
```

Comment: This is nice.  Much appreciated perspective.